# How do I listen for Map property changes in an object in dart

Tags: dart, properties

> Example

```
class Pony {
     Map _o ={};  
     get o => _o;  
     set o (v){
       print(v);
     }
}

void main() {
    var p = new Pony();
    p.o={}; //{}
    p.o['nothing']='no active'; //no print
}
```

**What I want is listen to Map property changes, what should  i do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation does not work since what you really are doing is to use get `get` call to access your internal map and then inserting a value to it.

I am not sure if it is important for you that the interface stays the same as in your example but I have made the following which changes a little how your are interacting with the `Pony` class:

```
class Pony {
  Map _o = {};

  Object operator [](Object key) => _o[key];
  void operator []=(Object key, Object value) {
    _o[key] = value;
    print('Key: "$key" updated with the value "$value"');
  }
}

void main() {
  var p = new Pony();
  p['nothing'] = 'no active';
  // Key: "nothing" updated with the value "no active"

  print('Value from map: ${p['nothing']}');
  // Value from map: no active
}
```